# How to use return with a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop function, that loop through an array of objects. What I want is that the output is returned, to be clear the variable `outputHTML`, but the `return` function, execute the loop process, so it will return only one time. How can I repeat this process?

```js
for (var i = 0; i < data.media.length; i++) {

  if (data.media[i].image != undefined) {

    outputHTML = '<div class="image">';

    // for (var j = 0; j < data.media[i].image.length; j++) {
    // console.log(data.images[i]);

    // Extract filename
    var url = data.media[i].image.src;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.lastIndexOf('.'));
    // console.log(filename);

    outputHTML += '<img src="' + url + '" alt="' + filename + '" />';
    // $("body").append(outputHTML);

    // };

    outputHTML += '</div>';

    return outputHTML;

  } else {
    // If image doesn't exists return empty string
    return '';
  }

};
```

Comment: Simply don't use `return` in this case? Just, dunno, `continue`? Or erase the whole `else` block altogether.

Comment: Why do you want multiple return statements?

Comment: If you want to do that, you should put it inside a function if you want to return something. Then when you call that function, it will return whatever you tell it to.

Comment: To be clear, do you want to return on every iteration of for loop ?

Comment: `return` means to return from the current function and continue execution from the line where where function was invoked. Once a `return` is executed it will immediately return from the function and will not execute anymore iteration of the loop. Think of it like *exit*

Answer (score 3):

Why not just `return` when your loop has finished?

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.media.length; i++) {
    ...
};
return outputHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var outputHTML = '';
for (var i = 0; i < data.media.length; i++) {

                if (data.media[i].image != undefined) {

                    outputHTML += '<div class="image">';

                    // for (var j = 0; j < data.media[i].image.length; j++) {
                        // console.log(data.images[i]);

                        // Extract filename
                        var url = data.media[i].image.src;
                        var filename = url.substring( url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.lastIndexOf('.') );
                        // console.log(filename);

                        outputHTML += '<img src="' + url + '" alt="' + filename + '" />';
                        // $("body").append(outputHTML);

                    // };

                    outputHTML +='</div>';



                } 

            };
return outputHTML;
```

Comment: Why leave the `else` at all?

Comment: And you're still reinitializing outputHTML on the third line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a function that you're telling to return. One would expect it to leave the function. Perhaps you want to combine all of the results together? In which case it is up to you to determine how they should be combined. e.g. by concatenation?

Answer (score 0):

You can either build up the outputHTML variable inside the for loop - and then return the variable after the loop is done executing - OR you could remove the for loop from the function and CALL it within a for loop.  I think the first option makes the most sense:

```
function GetOutputHTML(data){

    var outputHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < data.media.length; i++) {


                    if (data.media[i].image != undefined) {

                        outputHTML += '<div class="image">';

                        // for (var j = 0; j < data.media[i].image.length; j++) {
                            // console.log(data.images[i]);

                            // Extract filename
                            var url = data.media[i].image.src;
                            var filename = url.substring( url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.lastIndexOf('.') );
                            // console.log(filename);

                            outputHTML += '<img src="' + url + '" alt="' + filename + '" />';
                            // $("body").append(outputHTML);

                        // };

                        outputHTML +='</div>';

                    }     
                };
        return outputHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `data.media` is an `array` you could use the builtin map function to get an array with your desired outputs, and then join it:

```
var html = data.media.map(function(item, index) {

    if (item.image != undefined) {

        var outputHTML = '<div class="image">';

        var url = item.image.src;
        var filename = url.substring( url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.lastIndexOf('.') );

        outputHTML += '<img src="' + url + '" alt="' + filename + '" />';

        outputHTML +='</div>';

        return outputHTML;

    } 

    // Since you are returning from within the code block above 
    // (when the condition is true) you don't need to put an 
    // else statement.

    return '';

}).join('');
```